# Javascript, ajax - with xmlhttp - over https

Tags: javascript, https

I am using xmlhttp. I have an html page that activates a .js.
The .js access an https site.

Will this code run as if I've run it from the browser or rather, since this is .js file - I need to somehow propgate my certificates and do the all ssl dance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser will handle a request for an embedded Javascript resource using its standard mechanisms for authentication. After all, Javascript is just instructions to the browser.